# How to speed up writing binary file floats to vector, with stream or parallelism

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, mpi, scientific-computing

I am currently experimenting with speeding up some of my scientific calculations through parallelism, with Amazon Web Services EC2 servers along with MPI.  The problem basically is this:

I have a large binary file (~200MB) full of floats.  I open the file as a stream buffer.  I then use `pubseekpos()` and `sgetn()` to grab specific floats, about 4000 of them, from the binary file and write them to a vector.  These floats are scattered around the binary file, not grouped together.  I distribute the vector into a histogram, and fit the histogram to a set of functions.  I repeat this process ~8000 times, grabbing different sets of values from the binary float file.

A snippet of my read file code is below:

```
...
filebuf fb;
fb.open("test3.dat", ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);

int posStart = (8192*1000+4096+1+k)*4;
for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
{
    int posSkip = i*8192*4;
    fb.pubseekpos(posStart+posSkip);
    fb.sgetn((char*)&vec[i], sizeof(vec[0]));
}
...
```

Then `vector<float> vec` is filled into a histogram, fitted, etc.

The problem I have with speeding up this process is, most of the calculation time is in the binary file reading above.  About 50x longer than any histogram filling or fitting.  My original plan was to use MPI and several cloud nodes to split up the fitting, but that is a little pointless unless I can speed up this reading from file.

So I have 2 questions:

1)  Is there alternate, faster way to read from file, write the floats to `vector<float> vec`, and fill a histogram than I am currently using?

2)  Is there a way to parallelize the reading from file in (1), using MPI, so I can somehow split up the data before histogram and fitting?  So even if my slowest process is still the reading from file, that computation time can be divided over several nodes?

Comment: 1) It is often quicker to read the entire file once and perform the operations on the data before writing everything as a histogram at the end, use MPI if not enough RAM. 2) You can split the file over processes (by file offset) using MPI2 i/o, see e.g. http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_set_view.html. This requires the problem to be dividable based on the data layout in the file but you could perform you binning operations and `MPI_Reduce` the histogram at the end.

Comment: This looks much closer to what I am trying to do.  However, I cannot divide the binary file data _sequentially_.  For example, I need one process to read char index 0; 100; 200; 300,;etc, while I need the next process to look at char 1; 101; 201; 301; etc, and the next to read char 2; 102; 202; 302; etc.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: Do you have a single binary file or a collection of such? 200 MB is nothing fancy when it comes to loading it entirely in memory, given that most computing systems nowadays have multi GBs of RAM. A shared memory mapping should do the trick. And you might be better off using OpenMP than MPI when processing on a single node.